# Convert C# generic into Java generic

Tags: c#, java, generics

How can I convert the following C# code to Java?

```
private T GenericMethod<T>(String value)
{  
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value , true);  
}
```

Comment: Neither C# nor Java have templates. edit: edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wherever you call your method:

```
// C#
MyEnum value = TemplateMethod<MyEnum>("AnEnumValue");
```

In Java you can do it like this:

```
// Java
MyEnum value = MyEnum.valueOf("AN_ENUM_VALUE");
```

If you're worried about case, and if you follow Java conventions of using upper case enum values, then you can just do this:

```
MyEnum value = MyEnum.valueOf(anEnumValue.toUpperCase());
```

To encapsulate it in a method:

```
static <E extends Enum<E>> E parse(Class<E> enumType, String value) {
  return (E)Enum.valueOf(enumType, value.toUpperCase()); 
}
```

Call it like this:

```
MyEnum value = parse(MyEnum.class, anEnumValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

First change your method signature to the following :

```
private <T> T TemplateMethod(String value)
```